# iOS Will Screenshot Private API

Tags: objective-c, api, screenshot, private

I am trying to execute a function before a screenshot is taken in iOS/Objective-C. I have been browsing https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers however I'm not having much luck. This app won't be getting submitted to the App Store therefore it's okay to use private api's. Is there any way to do this?